# Can't find a particular model if its not in \App

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, namespaces

So I noticed something very strange when I deployed my project on a server (It works on local server) , one of my models doesn't work in "models" directory I've created, it only works when I put the model.php in \App and it has the namespace as the other models , how come?

namespace App\Http\Models;

Error: Class 'App\http\Models\Themodel' not found

Comment: Which mvc structure are you used?

Comment: Standard Laravel I guess , I've only put all models in a model directory instead of having them in \app, could you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: `'Http' != 'http'` ?

Comment: can you show us the definition of your class? Where exactly is the error thrown?

Comment: @Tomanow That was the problem haha *facedesk* , Didn't notice it because my IDE wouldnt tell error and it worked fine on localserver.

Answer (score 1):

If your models folder is in App\Models then the namespace should be:

```
 namespace App\Models;
```

In your controller import the model in your controller like this:

```
 use App\Models\Themodel;
```

Comment: Got it sorted, I had 'http' instead of 'Http' in the "use" statement